# How do you detect a number if it is in between 2 numbers in python?

Tags: python

I'm making a game where there are 3 numbers, the 1st and 2nd will be shown but the third will be hidden. If the 3rd number is in between the 1st and the 2nd, the user will win, if not then the user will lose. For example, the 1st number is 3 and the 2nd number is 6, and the user will guess if the 3rd number is in between the 2 numbers. So if the 3rd number is 5 which is in between 3 and 6 then the user would win, but if the 3rd number is 2 which is not in between 3 and 6 then the user will lose. Question is what comparisons do I have to make to do that? The code below is just an example of what I have done is not working properly

```
        if (trd_crd > fst_crd and trd_crd < snd_crd):
           print("Congrats, you win!")
```

Comment: `low < your_number < high`

Comment: @ForceBru That is exactly the same as the OP condition, just another way to write it, so it doesn't change the evaluation. So, if OP condition is wrong, this is wrong too.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"? The expression looks exactly as it should to perform the task you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have assumed your `fst_crd` to be smaller than `snd_crd` which is not the case, always. Sometimes you can have `fst_crd > snd_crd`, in that case you'll need to check `if fst_crd >trd_crd > snd_crd`.

So, i will recommend you to use :

`if((trd_crd > fst_crd and trd_crd < snd_crd) or (trd_crd > snd_crd and trd_crd < fst_crd)):         print("Congrats, You win!")`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `value1 < value2 < value3` works as you expect in math.

you can do:

```py
if(fst_crd < trd_crd < snd_crd):
    print("Conrgrats, you win!")
```

Comment: That is exactly the same as the OP condition, just another way to write it, so it doesn't change the evaluation. So, if OP condition is wrong, this is wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

What if the 3rd number is equal to either the 1st or 2nd numbers, in this case, you should have an `or equals` in the comparisons, so it should be `if (trd_crd >= fst_crd and trd_crd <= snd_crd):`, which can also be written as `if (fst_crd <= trd_crd <= snd_crd):`.